# Are public website s3 buckets vulnerable to DDoS attacks?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We are trying to make our web app the most cost effective and secure we can For that reason we are using Clodflare instead of ClodFront as a CDN four our frontend resources, but put CloudFront in between Cloudflare and S3 to be able to use Full SSL (strict), which is needed because we have a subdomain for API Gateway, which needs it to avoid infinite loops generated when using Cloudflare Flexibe SSL

The problem is that AWS documentation on connecting S3 with CloudFront for Website hosting instructs on allowing public access to the bucket contents ([1](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/)), while Cloudflare recommends restricting access to Cloudflare Servers IPs to disallow public requests to the website buckets ([2](https://miketabor.com/how-to-host-a-static-website-using-aws-s3-and-Cloudflare/), [3](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037983412-Configuring-an-Amazon-Web-Services-static-site-to-use-Cloudflare))

Specifically, we want to be able to use Cloudflare free DDoS protection effectively, avoiding potentially high costs related to receiving DDoS attacks directly into our AWS deployed resources, and the need of using other non free services as AWS WAF

So my question is, given an architecture using Cloudflare, CloudFront and S3 website bucket with public access bucket policy, is there a DDoS vulnerability, specifically with respect to CloudFront and S3 not being properly protected by Cloudflare?

Comment: I believe this is more appropriate for Information Security stackexchange.

Comment: Maybe, but I think I could get a faster response here If I get an answer here I will copy it there

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you wish to restrict access to the Amazon S3 bucket so that access is only available via CloudFront.

This can be done by creating an **Origin Access Identity** for the CloudFront distribution, then referencing this identity in the Bucket policy of the Amazon S3 bucket.

See: [Restricting Access to Amazon S3 Content by Using an Origin Access Identity - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

This way, the bucket is *not* public.

However, it would be possible to access the bucket by going to CloudFront (without first going via Cloudflare), but I imagine you would not be publicising the CloudFront URL so it is unlikely to happen.

Comment: As I have been researching, CloudFront OAI imposes an S3 REST endpoint instead of a Website S3 endpoint, which has severe limitations with respect to frontend routing rules the ones we do not feel comfortable taking over at our frontend developement https://sanderknape.com/2020/02/building-a-static-serverless-website-using-s3-cloudfront/